# Spark DataFrame repartition with Numeric column not working as expected

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark2.4.4. I understand df.repartition(n, col) is based on hash partition of col. Then why is it failing for numeric col

```
val df1 = spark.range(0,10,1).map( e => (e%2, e)).toDF("key", "value")
df1.repartition(2, $"key").foreachPartition{ it => println(it.toList)}
//List()
//List([0,0], [1,1], [0,2], [1,3], [0,4], [1,5], [0,6], [1,7], [0,8], [1,9])
```

But when I use string column, it looks ok

```
val df1 = spark.range(0,10,1).map( e => ((e%2).toString, e)).toDF("key", "value")
df1.repartition(2, $"key").foreachPartition{ it => println(it.toList)}
//List([1,1], [1,3], [1,5], [1,7], [1,9])
//List([0,0], [0,2], [0,4], [0,6], [0,8])
```

Answer (score 4):

> ... why is it failing for numeric col?

It is not failing. If you  look at the Plan:

```
== Physical Plan ==
Exchange hashpartitioning(key#9L, 2)
+- *(1) Project [_1#6L AS key#9L, _2#7L AS value#10L]
+- *(1) SerializeFromObject [assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple2, true])._1 AS _1#6L, assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple2, true])._2.longValue AS _2#7L]
+- *(1) MapElements <function1>, obj#5: scala.Tuple2
+- *(1) DeserializeToObject staticinvoke(class java.lang.Long, ObjectType(class java.lang.Long), valueOf, id#0L, true, false), obj#4: java.lang.Long
+- *(1) Range (0, 10, step=1, splits=1)
```

You can see that Spark use `hashpartitioning`.

All it means is that for integers, hash%2 of `0` and `1` gives the same results, while the hash of Strings `"0"` and `"1"` returns different value each. Try to repartition to 3 partitions instead of 2 and see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

You may be confused because`0 % 2 == 0` and `1 % 2 == 1` but Spark SQL uses Murmur3 to hash values, including integers. `0` and `1` Murmur3 hashes are mapped to the same value modulo 2.

*Note*: It can be troubling but Spark does not try at all to balance partitions when there is a very little number of keys, it's all up to the hashing function. The more n°keys/n°partitions is high, the more the balancing is expectable to be satisfying.

Comment: Indeed, standard java hashcode gives 0, 1 for 0,1 respectively. But murmur3 in spark gives even number for both 0,1
(even scala.util.hashing.MurmurHash3 gives even, odd). Looks like in spark murmur3 hash code for 0,1 are divisible by 2,4,8,16,....
In spark, this means boolean conditional on column in repartition(n,col) also would not rebalance the data if n is not suitably choosen.
 In RDD, atleast custom partioner can be selected.